# Divergence and convergence of series with radical fractions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I have a serie as follows:$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n-4}{\sqrt{n^3+n^2+8}}$$

since $\frac{n-4}{\sqrt{n^3+n^2+8}} \leq \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^3+n^2+8}}$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{n-4}{\sqrt{n^3+n^2+8}}}{\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^3+n^2+8}}} = \frac{n-4}{n} = 1$$

Is this series therefore convergent or am i missing something?

Comment: Well, the majorant series is **divergent**, so...

Answer (score 1):

An idea:

$$\frac{n-4}{\sqrt{n^3+n^2+8}}\ge\frac n{\sqrt{n^3+n^3+n^3}}=\frac{n-4}{3\sqrt{n^3}}$$

and now apply the limit comparison test to the above with the divergent series with general term $\;\cfrac1{\sqrt n}\;$ ...

Comment: What do you mean by the general term?

Comment: @Daniel In the series $\;\sum a_n\;$ , the general term is $\;a_n\;$ ...

Comment: Good to see you here, my friend !

Comment: @ClaudeLeiboviciBon jour, mon cher ami ! Glad to see you around.

Answer (score 1):

To see whether it converges or not, you can do some easy asymptotic analysis:

A polynomial is asymptotically equivalent to its leading term, i.e. $\;n-4\sim_\infty n$ and $\;n^3+n^2+8\sim_\infty n ^3$, so that
$$\frac{n-4}{\sqrt{n^3+n^2+8}}\sim_\infty\frac n{n^{\frac 32}}=\frac 1{\sqrt n},$$
and the latter diverges.

Now it is a basic theorem that two series with positive, asymptotically equivalent, general terms both converge or both diverge, whence the conclusion.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the theorem? Limit comparison doesn’t see to work in this case.

Comment: Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Shouldn't we have $\frac{n-4}{\sqrt{n^3+n^2+8}}\ \leq \frac 1{\sqrt n}$ to be true in order to use the theorem?

Comment: @Daniel Bernard is using the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test

Comment: @Daniel: using asymptotic analysis usually has the advantage to free you from examining unnecessary details. Note that it is valid only for series with ultimately constant sign terms.